# Using OpenView in Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

When I use OpenView in Domino Designer, all the **Views** are presented in the Menu Bar. How can I make sure that only one view is presented and at the same time do not hide the other **Views** so I can use them to other Hotspot Button. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Would you mind adding some context to this question by explaining Domino Designer, Views, Menu Bars etc... May be some images to elaborate the issue.

Comment: You don't need to explain Domino Designer, views and menu bars. But you do new to try to explain what you're trying to do a little better. What do you mean by "When I use OpenView"?  Are you talking about a formula that uses @Command([OpenView];...)? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create an outline with the views. You can organize the views in expandable groups, specify icons for each view, and much more.
You then create a page where you insert the outline, set the fonts and formatting, etc.
Finally you create a frameset and put the page with the navigation menu in one of the frames.
I created a simple template with all this several years ago, you can find it at http://blog.texasswede.com/free-application-templateframework-for-notes/

[image]
Download it and take a look at how it's done there.

Comment: I temporary fixed the problem by using the NavigatorsViewNone command. I mean, if I use the command OpenView, there is still a menu/list/navigator on the left side which displays the name and link of other views.

Comment: i'm referring to the @command(OpenView). I want to remove the navigation/menu bar which list all view names

Comment: You can hide all the views so they don't appear on the menu bar. You should still be able to use @Command([OpenView]) with them even though they are hidden. You might want to give them simple aliases so you don't have to use the full name of the views in your formula. And you might need to use parenthesis around the name of the hidden view in your formula - I don't recall if that is necessary in this context or not.

Comment: Thank you Richard. What command can I use to hide the views? Apologies but I'm really new to Domino Designer.

Comment: Can you also help me with this? My listbox contains - "1-Very Behind". If I only want to show 1 on the report, what should I do?